# how can i add arabic language with php

Tags: php, html

i want to create an interface of website in Arabic language....how can i do that...do i need any plugin to be already installed on my hosting server or mylocalhost how can i do that...please let me know in detail...

Comment: Is is just text for the interface or/and storing info in database in arabic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key for you is Unicode -- it's less an issue of the hosting server, and more an issue of you making sure that your web pages have proper content encoding headers.  PHP has had historic issue with internationalization and Unicode; you might want to read a few references before starting your development:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html);
- [Unicode for the working PHP programmer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html);
- Nick Nettleton's [PHP UTF-8 Cheat Sheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet);
- the [PHP unicode manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/book.unicode.php).

Comment: +1 for 'The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely'. I am now enlightened. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything extra to display text, just support for Unicode which is built into modern browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you save all your files as UTF-8 without BOM (or any Arabic-capable codepage). Make sure your Web service emits the right charset in Content-type (or put a meta tag in each page). Make sure your IDE is fine with UTF-8 files.

BOMs in UTF-8 PHP files, in particular, are pure evil.

The rest depends on your programming environment. Can't give more details.